# can't find volume of a room using dart

Tags: dart, methods, volume

is there any method to find a volume of a room in dart language (idk if it's language)

```
import 'dart:io';
class Room {
  int? height;
  int? length;
  int? width;

  int volume(){
    return (height!* length! * width!);
  }
}

void main(){
  Room room = Room();
  room.height = 10;
  room.length = 4;
  room.width = 5;
  print("Volume is ${room.volume()}.")Ж
}
```

this is the code i have which is working, but teacher said that there is its own method and i should be with it.

if you got a code for it, id be thankful, itd be even better if you plus have a url link of a site where i could learn about it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not don't quite understand your question but you could make your code simpler by making length, width and height required parameters for a room constructor. Like this:

```
class Room {
  int height;
  int length;
  int width;

  //constructor with required parameters
  Room({
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.length,
  });

  int volume() {
    return (height * length * width);
  }
}

void main() {
  Room room = Room(
    length: 4,
    width: 5,
    height: 10,
  );
  print("Volume is ${room.volume()}.");
}
```

Hope this helps :)